# How do I get method signatures or method descriptions in Ruby's irb?

Tags: ruby, irb

I'm wondering if Ruby's `irb` has the ability to supply method/function signatures or descriptions.

I know I can do something like this in the irb

```
[].methods.sort
```

and get all the methods/functions available to arrays but how can I get more information(while in the `irb`) about specific methods/functions?

Comment: Ruby 2.7 will imporove a lot irb documentation (when you press 2 times tab) https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/09/23/new-irb-features.html, they will integrate ruby's ri into irb, but... maybe there is a way to use ri from irb :)

Comment: Reopened because this was marked as a duplicate of the question where the accepted answer simply does not work (`Nothing known about Mechanize::Form#button`)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`#method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Object.html#method-i-method) and then use [`Method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Method.html) methods:

```
1.method(:+).arity
# => 1
1.method(:+).parameters
# => [[:req]]
[].method(:reduce).parameters
# => [[:rest]]
```

Comment: Its nice to see the irb is getting a bit of love in 2.7 because I always felt it was a bit of a weak spot for Ruby tools. Maybe I'm spoiled coming from OCaml's REPL's utop and ocaml(with the Down module) which provide function signatures and syntax highlighting and code completion and editor support.

Comment: Take a look at the `pry` gem. It should give you a lot of the features you need out of the box. I don't use irb usually, only pry.

Answer (score 0):

This is new for me as I've commented on ruby 2.7 they will improve irb's documentation. here is the pull request on [ruby core](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/559dca509d2a98584b09c7d9a6d74749ce793ad7) that to it.

If you read the pull request you are able to do this.

```
2.6.3 :003 > require 'rdoc'
 => true
2.6.3 :003 > driver = RDoc::RI::Driver.new
 => # here you will see all rdoc docs
2.6.3 :005 > driver.display_name("Bundler::CLI::Common")
```

Pretty Cool no?

Comment: `driver.display_name("Mechanize::Form#button") # => RDoc::RI::Driver::NotFoundError (RDoc::RI::Driver::NotFoundError)`